# Set shared_ptr to point existing object

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

For the code below, I would like to know how to set `std::shared_ptr` to point the given objects in the two member functions. The `Vector3` object which is allocated in the main function is not going to be deleted until the end of the program.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::shared_ptr;

class Vector3
{
    // ...
};

class Face
{
    vector < shared_ptr <Vector3> > vtx;

    public:

    void addVtx (const Vector3& vt)
    {
        // vtx.push_back (); <-- how to push_back ?
    }

    void setVtx (const int v, const Vector3& vt)
    {
        if ( vtx.size() > 0 && v < vtx.size() )
        {
            // vtx[v] = &vt; <-- how to assign ?
        }
    }

};

int main ()
{
    vector <Vector3> vec (3);
    Face face;

    face.addVtx (vec[0]);
    face.setVtx (0, vec[0])

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *The Vector3 object which is allocated in the main function is not going to be deleted until the end of the program* - who is deleting it? If you pass ownership to `shared_ptr` it'll delete the object when `use_count` drops to 0. It doesn't sound like you need `shared_ptr` at all. Is this an attempt to placate someone who told you *raw pointers are evil*?

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes, I heard that putting raw pointers into containers is an evil action.

Comment: Raw pointers that own resources are a bad idea. However, your use case seems to be storing pointers to objects with automatic storage duration in a container. There's nothing wrong with using raw pointers here. Also, if you are considering using a smart pointer, the first one you consider should be `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`.

Comment: But if you have a `std::vector` of pointers of `Vector3` (the names do not help here :D), where are the original objects? Inside another `std::vector<Vector3>`? Maybe conceptually it would be best if you made the "indirect" `vector` a `std::vector<typename std::vector<Vector3>::iterator>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not much point in using a `shared_ptr` for an automatically allocated object.

*Technically* you can do it, by giving the `shared_ptr` a deleter that doesn't do anything, and changing your `vtx` to be a vector of shared pointers to `const` vectors.

E.g. changing the declaration to

```
vector < shared_ptr <Vector3 const> > vtx;
```

and adding a pointer like this:

```
vtx.push_back( shared_ptr<Vector3 const>( &vt, [](Vector3 const*){} ) );
```

Disclaimer: untested code, not touched by a compiler.

However, unless you're going to also add pointers to vectors that need to be deleted, just use a vector of raw pointers. Or, just use a vector of vectors, and copy the in-data.

---

It's not a good idea to use raw pointers to hold ownership. For that use smart pointers.

But conversely, it's not a good idea to use ownership smart pointers to hold pure references to static or automatic objects. For that, use raw pointers or references.

In general. [image]

Comment: Smart pointers for ownership, standard pointers for references. Good advice.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the argument about whether using `shared_ptr` is a good idea or not, as explained by the accepted answer, you can use the following if you continue to use `shared_ptr`:

```
void addVtx (const Vector3& vt)
{
    vtx.push_back(std::make_shared<Vector3>(vt));
}

void setVtx (size_t v, const Vector3& vt)
{
    if ( vtx.size() > 0 && v < vtx.size() )
    {
       vtx[v] = std::make_shared<Vector3>(vt);
    }
}
```

Comment: One important point to be noted here is `std:make_shared` creates a copy of the object which is passed in the argument and uses that. That is the reason it works, eventhough shared pointers arent supposed to hold static addresses. If a copy is not desired, and if the pointer is used to edit the actual object, this method wont work, as the edited object will be a copy of the original object and changes wont reflect. Using a deleter which does nothing is the way to go in that case.