# Handling the validity of the object of a class stored in a different class

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics

I am trying to understand the preferred approach for a class to handle the validity of (reference to) the object of *another* class.

In here, `C` has a vector that stores references of `D` objects. If `D` and `C` are a part of the library, how should `C` handle the case where a `D` object goes out of scope in the caller?

A couple approaches that I have in mind though not sure of the feasibility:

- `D` knows about what `_list` stores and as soon as the said `D` goes out of scope, `~D()` runs which removes itself from `_list`.
- `_list` stores `weak_ptr` instead of a raw and upon any access to `D`, you invoke `weak_ptr::lock()` prior to accessing, though this will require the instantiation of a `shared_ptr` which seems to be not so common in production?

```
struct D
{
    ~D()
    {
        printf ("~D()\n");
    }
};

class C
{
    vector<D*> _list;

    public:
    void add(D* dObject)
    {
        _list.push_back(dObject);
        printf ("Adding D => size = %ld\n", _list.size());
    }

    ~C()
    {
        printf ("~C()\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c1;
    {
        D d1;
        c1.add(&d1);
    }

    /**
     _list[0] is garbage now. How to avoid accessing it i.e 
      C being aware to not access it?
    */
    printf ("----out of scope---\n"); 
    D d2;                   
    c1.add(&d2);
}
```

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is probably your best option.  (Assuming that there is a strong necessity to "handle the validity".)  I'm not a fan of `shared_ptr` (unless absolutely necessary) because I don't like federated ownership of a mutable variable, which is tantamount to having a global mutable variable.  If it's a `shared_ptr<const Foo>` then that's okay, since Foo is const.

Comment: You might want to be careful with your nomenclature.  Pointers and smart pointers are not references.   References are something else entirely in C++ (although it is possible to obtain a reference from a pointer, or a pointer from a reference, they have distinct characteristics and are not interchangeable).

Comment: @Eljay why `shared_ptr` over `weak_ptr` if `C` doesn't take any 'ownership' of `D`? (

Comment: @Peter yes I understand the difference but should've been more careful with the words here. Thanks

Comment: My fault, when I said `std::shared_ptr`, I meant (implicitly) to also use `std::weak_ptr` for the non-owning pointers.  I had assumed; I should have been explicit.

Comment: gotcha. so something like this? https://godbolt.org/z/E7hEW1zr1. (added prints to help understand better hopefully). `_list` shall contain invalid objects and it's totally fine given we won't be causing UB unlike with raw pointers?

Comment: Yes, something like that is what I have in mind.  However, again, I caution that (in my opinion) the `std::shared_ptr` is a solution of last resort.  Because of my disdain for federated ownership, and it makes the lifecycle of the shared object more difficult to reason about, and that the object becomes tantamount to being a global variable.  `shared_ptr` (with `weak_ptr`) can be used to model a single-owner relationship, but the constraint is by discipline/convention, not enforced by what the classes allow.

Comment: You're taking the address of a local variable.  Templates for managing pointers won't help you here - if this were inside another function (besides main) that was exiting, the stack storage would go away, taking the object with it.  You should only be doing this with heap objects allocated with new.

Comment: which example are you referring to? are you implying `new` is always required for shared_ptr?

Comment: Yes, `new` is always required for `shared_ptr` - directly or indirectly, as in `std::make_shared`

Comment: Just to clarify, what'd you mean by indirectly? You're implying this uses `new` indirectly `auto sp = std::make_shared<int>()`?

Comment: Yes, if you read the source or docs for make_shared, it explicitly creates a heap variable.

Comment: yes but how does that relate to the local variable going out of scope in your "answer", which I totally failed to understand. Or the wording of your answer is throwing me off specially when you say you can't use local variables. Like if unique_ptr allocates on the heap anyway so what's the concern and in what context are you saying this in regards to my original question?

Comment: I've made another edit to clarify my "answer".  Hopefully it's enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in c++, you should not keep any reference of the stack instance to some containers. It is dangerous with dangling memory accesses and you should add instances which is created on heap to your preferred container. In this case of, shared_ptr is useful and safe for managing the lifetime of your instance.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct D{
public:
    string _name;
    D(const string& name) : _name(name){}
    ~D(){
        printf("~D()\n");
    }
};

class C{
    vector<shared_ptr<D>> _list;
public:
    void add(shared_ptr<D> dObject){
        _list.push_back(dObject);
        printf("Adding D => size = %ld\n", _list.size());
    }
    void print() {
        for (const auto& d : _list) {
            printf("%s\n", d->_name.c_str());
        }
    }
    ~C(){
        printf("~C()\n");
    }
};

int main(){
    C c1;
    {
        c1.add(make_shared<D>("first D"));
    }
    c1.add(make_shared<D>("second D"));
    c1.print();
}
```

output:

```
Adding D => size = 1
Adding D => size = 2
first D
second D
~C()
~D()
~D()
```

Additional: remove an object by block scope

```
    C c1;
    {
        auto d = make_shared<D>("first D");
        shared_ptr<nullptr_t> D_deleter{ nullptr, [&](auto) { c1.remove(d); } };
        c1.add(d);
    } // d would be deleted here
```

Comment: If the container is also on the same stack, adding a local variable to it can be safer, as both variables can be hopefully seen in context.

Comment: Yes I understand the example but `_list` still stores a dangling reference towards the end but it isn't a problem since it's not being accessed, which means `shared_ptr` will continue to store dangling references as well. Is that how it's typically done?

Comment: @xyf If you want to remove some of object when block scoped out, you can use the custom deleter of shared_ptr. See additional code above. In this case, deleter could remove even the reference/pointer of object on stack from c1 vector.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatives are**

1. Using scope_exit (also called scope guard):

```
int main() {
    C c1;
    {
        D d1;
        c1.add(&d1);
        scope_exit d1_erase([&] {
            c1.erase(&d1);
        });
        // ... insert here other code within the inner scope
    }
    // ... insert here other code within the outer scope
    return 0;
}
```

You should use a `std::set` instead of a `std::vector` within `D` to more efficiently find and erase entries again. And of course `D` should publicly provide an `erase` or `delete` function.

`scope_exit` is part of the soon-to-be-published C++ Library Fundamentals v3 Technical Specification (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit). The implementation belonging to the accepted proposal is here: https://github.com/PeterSommerlad/SC22WG21_Papers/tree/master/workspace/P0052_scope_exit.

2. Creating a custom class managing adding and automatically deleting (also at scope exit) the pointer to and from the list from outside both classes:

```
class E
{
public:
    E(C& c, D* dp) : _c(c), _dp(dp) { _c.add(_dp); }; // add to list
    ~E() { _c.erase(_dp); };                          // remove from list

    E(const E&) = delete;            // rule-of-3
    E& operator=(const E&) = delete;

private:
    C& _c;
    D* _dp;
};

int main() {
    C c1;
    {
        D d1;
        E e(c1, &d1); // adds pointer to d1 to c1 list
                      // and removes it automatically at the end of the scope
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could also store `D` within `E` instead of referring to it by stored reference.

BTW: Destruction order for local scopes is in reverse order to construction.

Those two solutions keep `C` and `D` as they are. You have to decide yourself, whether `C` intrusively should have knowledge of its `D` object or whether its addition and removal from `D` is handled non-intrusively like in those two solutions.

I would not use a `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` for those cases, where the objects are stored locally and the time of destruction is clear (when leaving scope either at its end or due to an exception or a `return` statement).

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, the original question is asking: "how do I know when a local variable goes out of scope?"

The answer is: when its destructor is called.

**For the code in your question**, you could have `~D()` to remove itself from `c1`.
This is awkward, and the discussion beneath the question brings up `std::shared_ptr`,
but the code in the example uses a local variable.  You can't use `std::shared_ptr`
on a local variable, only on a heap variable.  This is not made clear in the discussion.

Here are two references to questions specifically related to shared_ptr and local variables:

[Create shared_ptr to stack object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855343/create-shared-ptr-to-stack-object)

and

[Set shared_ptr to point existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049155/set-shared-ptr-to-point-existing-object)

A better solution to your problem is to not use a local variable, but a heap variable.

The difference between local and heap variables seems to be causing some confusion.

C++ has several storage classes for variables:

- stack - used for local variables and function parameters
- register - sometimes used for local variables - primarily an optimization
- global/static - "one and only one", in space allocated at program load time.
- thread local - global/static but thread specific - each thread has its own copy.
- heap - allocated by the program, on the fly, via new or malloc (or equivalent).  Sometimes called "free store".

C++ has some tricks with `new` and `delete` where you can use a custom heap,
which is memory you're managing yourself, but that memory will have been allocated
from the general heap, or possibly exist inside other variables.

Here are three different examples:

### A local variable:

```cpp
void some_function(C& c1)
{
    D d1;
    c1.add(&d1);
}
```

When this function exits, the stack frame that contains d1 goes away,
and the variable ceases to exist. `~D()` will get called,
and you could remove d1 from c1 if you added
a mechanism to do this, like making `d1` hold a pointer to `c1`, etc.,
which is awkward, but possible.

`std::shared_ptr` will not help with a local variable.

### A heap variable allocated with new:

```cpp
void some_function(C& c1)
{
    D *d1p = new D();
    c1.add(d1p);
}
```

When this function exits, the `D` variable that `d1p` points to still exists.
It will continue exist until it is explicitly deleted.  In this context,
the `c1` variable "owns" this pointer, and it responsible for deleting it
when it has finished using it.

This is the case where adding a smart pointer can simplify reference management,
as in:

### A heap variable and shared_ptr created via make_shared:

```cpp
void some_function(C& c1)
{
    std::shared_ptr<D> d1p = std::make_shared<D>();
    c1.add(d1p);
}
```

This example creates a `D` variable on the heap, and creates a local `shared_ptr`
holding a reference to that `D` variable, via a small counter object,
which is also on the heap.  When the `shared_ptr` is passed to the `C::add` method,
the reference count in the counter object is incremented.  When the `shared_ptr`
goes out of scope, the reference count in the counter object is decremented.
The `shared_ptr` in the `c1` object now holds the only reference to that `shared_ptr`,
and when the `c1` object is destroyed, the `shared_ptr` it contains will be destroyed,
releasing its reference - if the count goes to zero, the object it points to will
also be destroyed.

Besides this automatic destruction, another advantage of this approach is that you can get references to this `D` variable
from `c1` and use them elsewhere, and these references (and the `D` variable itself)
can outlive `c1`.

The `C` class has to be modified for this case, e.g.

```cpp
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<D>> _list;
```

and

```cpp
    void add(std::shared_ptr<D> dObject)
```

Here's a reference to how shared pointers work:

[How do shared pointers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802953/how-do-shared-pointers-work)

and some documentation on make_shared:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

Comment: so you're saying `auto s = std::make_shared<Class>();` is completely wrong? I still fail to understand why would not using heap allocation be a problem. If the object gets deleted so be it. There's why `lock` exists for `weak_ptr` such that you only access the shared object if it's valid/not null. Sorry, downvoting cause it doesn't answer the question

Comment: `make_shared` uses new inside the template, that's no longer a stack variable.  I've edited the answer to try and clear up some confusion.

Comment: The `scope_exit` technique from Sebastian's answer is good-to-know.  My C++ usage is rusty.